# Angular page does not reflect updates, it stays cached

Tags: angular

I have a small angular app that displays pictures from the assets folder. There is a json file that holds all of the information of the photo which includes name, caption, location of image, ect.

There is a service that is called that returns all the photos information.

**Service:**

```
 getAllPhotos(){
   return this.http.get(this.photoPath);
 }
```

This is passed to the component which stores the response in an array:

**Component**

```
this._data.getAllPhotos().subscribe(res => { this.data = res;
  console.log(this.data);
});
```

In the html page I loop through the data and bind to the template.

**HTML Page**

```
<img mat-card-image src="{{ photo.location }}" flex>
```

When this runs on local host the changes are reflected, although when I publish to host and view the page on its domain the page and pictures are cached and the updates are not reflected.

Can someone shed a bit of light on this, thanks.

Comment: What is not updated? The application itself or the some modified images?

Comment: When I add new photos to the assets folder, and json file they don't show in on the host. Although they do show in local host.

Comment: Can we see the content of the json file? And how you access/read that file? And how you refer to the `assets` folder content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent the Angular application from being cached, add the following lines to `index.html` head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

---

To prevent the browser from using the cached version of an image, you can add a different query string to the source URL. For example, if a `version` number is defined in code and incremented when the application is updated, you can set the image source this way:

```
<img [src]="photo.location + '?version=' + version" ...>
```

Comment: S I have this in the index.html,  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

Comment: I added a method to force the browser to reload the image.

Comment: This worked for the photo, but still reading the cache version of the json file, I will have to append it there as well. Thanks.